# .htaccess setenvif referer blocking IE6/7/8, working with IE9/FF/Chrome/Safari?

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, internet-explorer-8, referrer

I have a frustrating issue where I'm restricting traffic to a web application I've built using a simple SetEnvIf Referer method in htaccess, and htaccess is wrongfully blocking qualified IE6/7/8 traffic from only ONE of the 'allowed' sites.

Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9 have no problem getting in.

There are domains allowed:

1) traffic coming from the same domain as the app

2) traffic coming from the website of our customer

3) cnn.com *for the sake of testing another 3rd party.

For the case of CNN.com, I'm using browser tools to replace the target of a link on-screen with a new target: my web app address.

I've found the following:

Internal traffic works, per .htaccess rule

CNN.com traffic works

Traffic coming from the customer's site doesn't work in IE6/7/8 (9: works)

I've also built a simple php script that prints the HTTP_REFERER from $_SERVER. I'm using the same browser-tools method of inserting links on 3rd party pages, clicking them, and looking for the results on my test page. I've found:

internal traffic reports properly in all browsers

cnn.com traffic reports properly in all browsers

the 3rd party/customer website is not getting the referrer sent through IE(8). IE9 works.

.htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Referer samedomain\.com intra_site_referral=1
SetEnvIf Referer addressthatdoesntwork\.org intra_site_referral=1
SetEnvIf Referer another3rdpartyaddressthatworks\.org intra_site_referral=1
#SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" intra_site_referral=0
<FilesMatch "\.(html|js|css|jpg)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from env=intra_site_referral
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 403 /restricted.html
```

My questions:

Have I exhausted all possible errors on my end?

Can I conclude that something is wrong with the customer's website/server reporting of referrer?

Before you tell me htaccess referrer isn't 'safe' and referrers can be faked:
This protection method is not critical. It was meant to merely keep the audience of the app limited to internal team and the audience of our customer, to some extent.

Thanks for reading..

Comment: The directives in your .htaccess file look fine (though you may want to use `SetEnvIfNoCase`), if clicking links from your customer's site isn't including referers, not sure if there's anything you can do on your end.

Comment: it seems the customers site is reporting referrers, as shown in the other browsers, but that IE is not passing it along, for whatever reason. I'll try the setenvifnocase

Comment: same result with SetEvIfNoCase :/ but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using mod_rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !samedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !addressthatdoesntwork\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !another3rdpartyaddressthatworks\.org [NC]
RewriteRule \.(html|js|css|jpg)$  - [F]
```